# CALayerInvalidGeometry exception during HTML5 video play

Tags: ios, c, position, calayer, ios-4.2

After updating to the iOS 4.2 SDK, I receive the following exception in my app:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 22]'
```

(Please see below for the copy of call stack)

Details:

'- `UIWebView` with video tag is inside `UIScrollView`

'- Video can play inside `UIWebView`, but when tried to zoom in, and use either zoom-out or done button from the player, the app crashes with the said exception.
This doesn't happen on SDK 3.2

```
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x01150be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x012a55c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x01109628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0110959a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
 4   QuartzCore                          0x0200996a _ZL18CALayerSetPositionP7CALayerRKN2CA4Vec2IdEEb + 177
 5   QuartzCore                          0x020098b5 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 42
 6   QuartzCore                          0x020097cc -[CALayer setFrame:] + 763
 7   UIKit                               0x0030d307 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 255
 8   UIKit                               0x003e6add -[UISlider setFrame:] + 166
 9   MediaPlayer                         0x00f0faee -[MPDetailSlider setFrame:] + 78
 10  MediaPlayer                         0x00f267b7 -[MPWildcatFullScreenVideoOverlay layoutSubviews] + 1280
 11  QuartzCore                          0x0200e451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
 12  QuartzCore                          0x0200e17c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
 13  QuartzCore                          0x0200737c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
 14  QuartzCore                          0x020070d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
 15  QuartzCore                          0x020377d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
 16  CoreFoundation                      0x01131fbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
 17  CoreFoundation                      0x010c70e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
 18  CoreFoundation                      0x0108fbd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
 19  CoreFoundation                      0x0108f240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
 20  CoreFoundation                      0x0108f161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
 21  GraphicsServices                    0x01a85268 GSEventRunModal + 217
 22  GraphicsServices                    0x01a8532d GSEventRun + 115
 23  UIKit                               0x002e642e UIApplicationMain + 1160
 24  ecom                                0x000022c0 main + 102
 25  ecom                                0x00002251 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 6):

Since iOS 4.2 there seems to be an issue with the calculations of the frame size for the slider inside the MoviePlayer.

If the **width** of the frame is set between **143.0** and **235.0** this exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing a similar issue with my UIScrollView. I noticed this warning in the iOS docs:

> Important: You should not embed
>   UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so,
>   unexpected behavior can result because
>   touch events for the two objects can
>   be mixed up and wrongly handled.

I had a UITextView embedded within the scrollView. Removing that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with a class inheriting from a UIScrollView. The solution was pretty odd: Instead of using "initWithFrame" I just used "init" and set the frame manually in the next line. This solved the problem for me.

The problem occured only on one specific object - I created objects of the same type with "initWithFrame" in other parts of my program without problems. The problem also occured only on an iPhone 4 with iOS 4.2. It did worked without problems on iPhone 4 with iOS 4.1 and on an iPad with iOS 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I've started having the same expcetions with 4.2 and Xcode 4.2.5 (*only in simulator* - never on the real 4.2 device) and with CAGradientLayer code for gradient-background for cells - which is otherwise working fine on handful of other applications ,

luckily,

surrounding the code with Try-Catch block does produce expcetion sometimes, but no visible artefacts appear, all the cells do still have gradient backgrounds.